# Force Exclude files from PHPUnit Code Coverage

Tags: symfony1, phpunit, symfony-1.4, code-coverage

Is it possible to forcefully exclude a folder from PHPUnit's code coverage?

Problem I've got is, that I have a Symfony 1.4 project, which has folders at `./lib/vendor/symfony/*`. I want to exclude anything that's inside `./lib/vendor/*` - recursively.

Now, I want to exclude them whether they were covered implicitly by my tests or not, i.e. I never want to see these folders. So, I've added this bit to my `phpunit.xml` config file, but it doesn't seem to exclude these folders, no matter what I do:

```
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <exclude>
            <directory>./lib/vendor/*</directory>
            <directory>./lib/vendor/symfony/lib/*</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

It appears to me the moment code gets hit and XDebug notices it, PHPUnit will include it in the code coverage no matter what. The downside for me with this is, that this code is already tested by Symfony developers, so no need to include it in my coverage report, messing up my numbers :P

Comment: Have you tried to remove `*` from path?

Comment: @j0k yeah I tried that, tried just about everything, vendor, vendor/, vendor/*, vendor/*/ and vendor/*/*

Comment: I was just having a similar issue and the way I interpreted the above structure was to **exclude** the ```<directory>```'s from being included in the **whitelist**.

As opposed to the ```<blacklist><exclude>``` which would **exclude** the ```<directory>```'s from being included in the **blacklist**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok, so I thought that you can have either the blacklist section OR the whitelist section, turns out you can have both, so I blacklisted those folders and it worked:

```
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
              <directory>./lib/vendor</directory>
              <directory>./lib/helper</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
```

Comment: Note to self. This needs to be inside <filter>...</filter>

Comment: Blacklisting is not supported anymore by Php_Code_Coverage library.

Answer (score 34):

The correct way to exclude certain files from the coverage report in more or less recent versions of PHPUnit is to use `<exclude>` directive instead of `<blacklist>`. E.g.:

```xml
  <filter>
    <whitelist>
      <directory suffix=".php">src/</directory>
        <exclude>
           <directory suffix=".php">src/Legacy/</directory>
           <file>src/example.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
```

For more recent PHPUnit using newest schema this will be:

```xml
  <coverage>
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">src/</directory>
    </include>
    <exclude>
      <directory suffix=".php">src/Legacy/</directory>
      <file>src/example.php</file>
    </exclude>
  </coverage>
```

Comment: The suffix filter on this answer made a *huge* difference to the performance of my coverage report generation; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Observation: whitelisting (the directories you want to be included in the code coverage) makes the phpunit execution of the entire test suite quicker, compared to blacklisting.

```
<filter>
    <whitelist>
          <directory>/my/project/directory/to/be/covered</directory>
          ....
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Tested with: PHPUnit 4.5.0 and PHP 5.5.9

Answer (score 2):

As of recent versions of PHPUnit 10.x, this seems to have changed again with the removal of the <filter> element and changes to the parent element for the <include> / <exclude> tags, requiring a new solution. According to what is in the official docs for the configuration file, the [<source>](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.5/configuration.html#the-source-element) element now appears to be the new basis for applying project file filters via the <include> and <exclude> tags.

Here is a mostly working phpunit.xml example in relation to the OP using the new  element structure. Add the <source> block into your existing <phpunit> block contents.

```xml
<phpunit ...>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">app</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib</directory>
            <!-- Add any other project directories you want included by PHPUnit here -->
        </include>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/vendor</directory>
            <!-- Filter down additional unwanted subdirectories here -->
        </exclude>
    </source>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers all seem to apply to older versions of `PHPUnit`

I was running `PHPUnit 5.7.23` and had issues getting files included and excluded for `phpunit`. The [syntax](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.whitelisting-files) seems to have changed substantially and is only partially backward compatible.  I had a complex requirement where i needed to also included & excluded separate directories for code coverage (its a legacy system).

Here is what I required in `phpunit.xml`:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit Tests">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>

        <exclude>./tests/blah/excluded_file_from_tests1.php</exclude>
        <exclude>./tests/blah/excluded_file_from_tests2.php</exclude>
        <exclude>./tests/blah/excluded_file_from_tests3.php</exclude>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./common/lib/included_directory</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">./common/lib/included_directory/core/blah/excluded_directory</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

So:

- Under `<testsuites>` I'm including `./tests` directory
- But, under `.tests` i wanted to exclude a set of files `excluded_file_from_testsX.php`
- Then, i wanted to whitelist a directory `./common/lib/included_directory`
- But, under that included directory below a few levels is a directory i also wanted to exclude (./common/lib/included_directory/core/blah/excluded_directory).

So this seemed to work well when run via `phpunit --coverage-html build/coverage`

Answer (score 1):

Works with PHPUnit 9.0.1

```
<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">DIRECTORY_TO_ADD</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">ANOTHER_DIR_TO_ADD</directory>
        <exclude>
            <file>ANOTHER_DIR_TO_ADD/file1_to_not_include.php</file>
            <file>ANOTHER_DIR_TO_ADD/file2_to_not_include.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```