# phpUnit code coverage on interfaces shows no success

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm

Currently I am doing a whitebox test so the parent class and all interfaces are tested. This covers them all so I add the doc comment:

```
/**
 * @covers \Pat\Environment\PHP\Autoloader\Psr0<extended>
 */
public function testWhitebox() {}
```

phpUnit runs with success but the interface does not appear in the coverage.xml file. No matter if excluded or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <file>*Interface.php</file>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="./coverage.xml"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

The phpStorm IDE keeps counting it as file and therefor it is missing. Without that issue it would be 100% code coverage.

[image: Code coverage in phpStorm]

It is open for phpStorm and fixed for IntelliJ IDEA.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14785

Any known workaround?

Comment: How to cover something that doesn't even exist? *Coverage* is a *code coverage*. And you (by definition) don't have any implementations to test in interfaces.

Comment: Well it counts as a file and that is missing in the XML. Then it is up to phpStorm or PHPUnit.

Comment: I'm not sure I properly understand the question. Interfaces contain no executable code. How do you want to test them? What should be covered?

Comment: Also please add the commandline how you invoke PHPUnit to the question to add some more context.

Comment: I think you misinterpret the summary given next to the directory. It is perfectly correct to say 66% of the files are code-coveraged (it shows that there are some files that can not be covered at all for examples). As you can see, it says 100% of the lines. That value is important in your case. Not the file-percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to fix that?

If this qualifies as a bug/flaw/new feature request in PHPStorm, you can report it as an issue in their [issue tracker for PHPStorm (and other products)](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard).

Their personnel will then take care to fix that.

---

If you do not want to go that route, you can just ignore the file in your code-coverage statistics because you don't need to take it into account when calculating the percentage.

- [Force Exclude files from PHPUnit Code Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14379569/367456)

Comment: Thanks. It is solved in IntelliJ but not solved for phpStorm. I saw the force discussion but this didn't work (see new information above). Still counting every file.